# Separating codebehind and controls

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, wcf-ria-services

I'm using silverlight 4 and telerik rad controls. What is the best way to seperate the logic for the controls into another c# assembly? E.g. all the code where I say radCtrl.ItemSource = ""; etc, I want in another assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you don't want to set the ItemsSource and stuff like that in code behind.
Have a look at the MVVM Pattern (http://jesseliberty.com/2010/05/08/mvvm-its-not-kool-aid-3/). This is a really cool approach to seperate you View from your "data". If you want it in own assemblys, you create a View assembly and a ViewModel assembly. To display the data you use bindings.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Does WCF Ria Services have any relevance here?

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem. I'm not that into WCF Ria Services, but the services are basically your model.

Comment: John Papa has a great video showing an implementation with MVVM and RIA.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Silverlight-Firestarter/Silverlight-Firestarter-2010-Session-4-MVVM-Why-and-How-Tips-and-Patterns-using-MVVM-and-Service-Pat

Answer (score 0):

Well. like TerenceJackson there is the MVVM option
but in the most simple concept of of separation, which isn't really that separate, it's just that the C# won't be connected to the Xaml:

1. Create a Xaml (let's say, MyControl.Xaml).
2. Create a Class which inherits from Control (MyControlCode.cs).
3. in the constructor add:

   ```
       DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControlCode);
   ```
4. in the Xaml, reference the namespace of the project, and create an instance of the object:

that's it.